# Entity Framework core one-to-zero-or-one when both entities can exist stand alone

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two different entities, and both can live without the other: Contact (can be a person, a company, a school, etc) and Teacher (not really, but for the sake of understanding the problem).

Both entities can exist in the database with no reference to each other. However, a Teacher may or may not be a Contact. I have the property ContactId? on Teacher and the corresponding nullable field on the database, but *with no FK defined* (don't know what, not sure if I can change this nor if it matters here).

When I retrieve contacts, I want to retrieve the Teacher record if it exists, and it's not working. Currently there is no error but it's not retrieving the teacher data. Here are my classes:

```
public partial class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Contact")]
    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}

public partial class Teacher
{
    public int TId { get; set; } // don't ask about the property name :(

    public int? ContactId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContactId")]
    [InverseProperty("Teacher")]
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
}
```

Any help or ideas will be appreciated!

Comment: `public int TId { get; set; } // don't ask about the property name :(` I am going to ask about this property name. Why isn't it mapped properly. Your POCO should be clean of stupidity of your database. That is why it is called an ORM.

Comment: For me, this works with ef-core (1.1.1.0). EF created a database using your classes (including a unique index `IX_Teachers_ContactId`) and added some data. Next, I removed the FK constraint on `ContextId` and successfully queried `context.Contacts.Include(c => c.Teacher)`.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, @GertArnold! It turns out the field in the database was bigint in stead of int :( sigh legacy databases. That goes to you, too, @Aron!

Comment: You might want to check if the database has this unique index to enforce 1:1. If it has, the legacy isn't *that* bad :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, cannot comment yet so adding this as an answer.

Is your data being stored in your database properly? If yes, then it's simply a query issue. Remember, you will need to Explicitly Load (`.Include`) the properties you want to retrieve from your database. Unfortunately at this time Entity Framework does not have Lazy Loading like previous versions.

Example:

```
.Include(contact => contact.Teacher)
.Include(teacher => teacher.Contact)
```

If you're dealing with an `ICollection<Contact>` or `ICollection<Teacher>` you are able to use the same include properties, but the child property may not show up in Intellisense.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I had tried this but got an error, but now reinspecting that error I see the field Teacher.ContactId is bigint in stead of int. I changed that and it worked. :(